# Is the dependance of events in probability an equivalence relation?

Tags: probability, equivalence-relations

Is the dependance of events in probability an equivalence relation ?

If we note $D$ this relation, it’s intuitive that for $x,y$ events, we have $xDy$, $xDy$ if and only if $yDx$ but, is it a transitive relation ?

Comment: No it isn't transitive. Take two non-constant independent $X, Z$ and let $Y = X + Z$. Then $X, Y$ and $Y, Z$ are dependent but $X, Z$ is not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.